# Stop background animating after unlocking MacBook?

Tags: macos

After updating to the latest macOS on my MacBook the screen saver and background animate. Can I disable this?

I don't want to reduce other types of motion. Its only really the background animation that annoys me.

Comment: Which screensaver and Desktop picture are you using, and what were they before? Have you tried changing them to something else? I have a static picture for my Desktop. (The screensaver, I kind of expect to be animated.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about the animated wallpaper on the Lock Screen, that continues moving for a short time after unlocking -- it's under Screen Saver settings, uncheck "show as wallpaper".

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, it's a bug in Sonoma 14.1 - at least for me it was fixed after updating to 14.1.1. Now the animation runs as it did before: animated while the screen is locked, then stopping the animation about 1 or 2 seconds after unlocking.

Comment: For me, it was the opposite - it was fine <14.1.1, but after updating the animation DOESN'T stop after unlocking!